# Restoring chrome new-tab w/o uninstalling my extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension whick among other things is replacing the new-tab functionallity.
But since i can't restore all the new-tab functionallity (account sync login,bookmarks,web apps,recent sites,most popular).
I want the users to be able to restore the default new tab, w/o uninstalling my extension.

From my investigation there is the internal chrome scheme: "**chrome-internal://**" whick has the URL : **chrome-internal://new-tab/** .
When i try to navigate to it from my extension it does not seem to work (premission denied,although i requested it within the mainfest).
But when navigating to it from chrome (js console) it does show the default new tab.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Two things.. First, aim to make your new tab page BETTER than the default one. That way, if they're switching, it's because they prefer the feel of the default one, and you should let them switch. Second, they can disable it without uninstalling it, so you don't really have to worry about providing another way to disable it. It's very easy to do.

Comment: @DanRedux first of all thanks for the comment,second i'm aiming to make my page better but for now not all can be restored and the users might be angry (i'm seeing it in the leacing rates/feedback). my question was how to let them switch. My users aren't the most tech-savy (and even i don't know to disable the new-tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Chrome extension, you can set a tab to display the original chrome new tab page by calling `update` on it:

```
chrome.tabs.update({
    url: 'chrome-internal://newtab/'
});
```

The ["New Tab"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab/adcpijkmbecohfalcbafjgadfnpchhlg) chrome extension does this. [View the code on GitHub](https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-new-tab/blob/e705facdca77f575ad3d8b66df1c43be2b34088e/app.js#L38).

Comment: '`chrome-internal://newtab/`' is not actual with Chrome 33+. Use '`https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab`' url instead

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right. from Chrome 33+

```
https://www.google.co.jp/_/chrome/newtab?ie=UTF-8
```

replace `chrome-internal`

and `chrome://apps` works.